# Making a deck of cards, not callable after 1 iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a novice at programming, especially Python, so I'm not really familiar with classes in general, but I've looked around and couldn't find anything that would help. I have the classes Card and Deck defined, and in the Deck class, I have a deal function, which deals the top card. While the code works the first time, whenever I try to deal another card, the program returns "TypeError: 'Card object is not callable." Here's the code:

```
import random
deck = []


class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return "The {} of {}".format(self.value, self.suit)


class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        suits = ['Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Clubs', 'Spades']
        values = ['Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
        for i in suits:
            for j in values:
                deck.append(Card(i, j))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "There are {} cards left in the deck".format(len(deck))

    def shuffle(self):
        if len(deck) == 52:
            random.shuffle(deck)
        else:
            Deck()
            deck.shuffle()

    def deal(self):
        self.deal = deck[0]
        deck.remove(self.deal)
        return self.deal


d1 = Deck()
d1.shuffle()
print(d1.deal())
print(d1.deal())
print(d1)
```

Upon the second "print(d1.deal())," the program returns an error after dealing the first card, and when I debug it, the error is only occurring in that line. Anyone know what's wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Calling the `deal()` method assigns to `self.deal`, which is the same name as the method you just called.  Trying to call it again calls *that card* (which fails because it's not a callable object), not the original method which has been overridden.

Comment: Ah, got it! I just changed self.deal to a new variable and it works now. Thanks @jasonharper!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first lin of the Deck.deal method, you override the deal method by `deck[0]`.
In Python methods are just a kind of attribute, so they are in the same name-space.

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding the method. The following change to the deal function is necessary:

```
def deal(self):
    self.card = deck[0]
    deck.remove(self.card)
    return self.card
```

Answer (score 1):

The `deal` method is being overwritten by the first statement within itself. If you change the method to something like

```
def deal(self):
    self.top_card = deck[0]
    deck.remove(self.top_card)
    return self.top_card
```

it will work. Consider installing the pylint extension for your text editor if it's available. It gives a helpful error: "an attribute defined in python line 33 hides this method."